# Have shell inherit buffer local process-environment

Tags: shell, environment, buffer-local

I have made buffer local changes to `process-environment' using the technique described in [How can I get buffer-local environment variables via .dir-locals](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/35965/6783). I then call shell from that buffer. If I then view the environment variables in that shell using the following command, the buffer local changes are not included.

```
set | sort
```

I have used C-h v process-environment to confirm that the buffer local changes were made. However, if I added a variable in the buffer local process-environment it is not available in the shell.

For example, I set the environment variable P4ROOT in the buffer local process-environment. When I open a shell from that buffer, the P4ROOT environment variable is not set in the shell.

Comment: Tumbleweed? Really? Come on. Someone must have an answer to this. Well, I will eventually figure it out and answer my own question.

Comment: I have discovered the buffer-local-value function. I think this might be part of the solution, but I am still searching for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's actually a bit tricky on account of how `shell` is written, so the following is quite implementation-specific and could break if things change upstream; however, give this a whirl:

```el
(defadvice make-comint-in-buffer (before my-shell-dir-locals)
  (when (string= (ad-get-arg 0) "shell")
    (hack-dir-local-variables-non-file-buffer)))
(ad-activate 'make-comint-in-buffer)
```